# Can any USB mouse or keyboard be connected to the PS/2 connector of a motherboard via USB-PS/2 adapter?

Tags: usb, keyboard, motherboard, mouse, ps2

Is there a necessity for the mouse to know a different protocol or a different pinout to be able to be connected to a PS/2 port?

Many vendors provide a USB-to-PS/2 adapter, but some don't.

From what I know, PS2 and USB interfaces even have a different number of pins. How would such an adapter work?

Will the device have the same performance as before?

Is it necessary for the USB device to 'know' it is connected to a PS/2 port? I suppose it is necessary since USB-to-PS/2 adapters are just that: adapters, not converters. They do not do anything to the signal, so probably the keyboard or mouse should know and adapt their signal accordingly.

And another question: Is there any latency added when connecting a USB keyboard or mouse to a PS/2 port using an adapter? I suppose the adapter itself does not add latency since it only connects some pins to some others, but inside the mouse or keyboard something has to change. The mouse has to switch to PS/2 data serialization instead of USB. In theory, PS/2 should be faster, but I am thinking that if that particular device is made to work natively on USB, it could have sort of an internal signal converter which may generate some latency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a necessity for the mouse to know a different protocol or a
> different pinout to be able to be connected to a PS/2 port?

Yes, it is necessary for the USB mouse to support the PS/2 protocol to be connected to P/2.  I can imagine there's someone somewhere that made an adapter somewhere that proves this false but that's a rare exception that would cost more than just buying another mouse and therefore be a personal design challenge than any viable mass produced product.

> Many vendors provide a USB-to-PS/2 adapter, but some don't.
>
> From what I know, PS2 and USB interfaces even have a different number
> of pins. How would such an adapter work?

Of the six pins on a PS/2 port only 4 are used. For reference see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port

An exception (pointed out in the linked article) would be some laptop PS/2 ports that use the normally unconnected pins to allow for a splitter that can split the single PS/2 port into two PS/2 ports.

An educated guess is that the mouse knows which kind of port it is connected to by switching polarity on the power pins, put the +5V on one pin and the data pins "talk" USB, put +5V on the other pin and the data pins "talk" PS/2.  There must be a dozen different ways to make it work, and I suspect most of them had been tried by different mouse manufacturers over time.  Knowing how any given mouse does this detection would require some investigation.

> Will the device have the same performance as before?

Yes and no.  Those that like to tweak their hardware for maximum gaming performance will prefer PS/2 over USB for reasons that can get complicated quickly so I won't go into details on that.  For most any user the performance difference would be unnoticeable.  PS/2 allows for better performance but that doesn't mean a mouse will work better with PS/2 than USB since there could be some other weak link in that chain than the port used to connect to the computer.

> Is it necessary for the USB device to 'know' it is connected to a PS/2
> port? I suppose it is necessary since USB-to-PS/2 adapters are just
> that: adapters, not converters. They do not do anything to the signal,
> so probably the keyboard or mouse should know and adapt their signal
> accordingly.
>
> And another question: Is there any latency added when connecting a USB
> keyboard or mouse to a PS/2 port using an adapter? I suppose the
> adapter itself does not add latency since it only connects some pins
> to some others, but inside the mouse or keyboard something has to
> change. The mouse has to switch to PS/2 data serialization instead of
> USB. In theory, PS/2 should be faster, but I am thinking that if that
> particular device is made to work natively on USB, it could have sort
> of an internal signal converter which may generate some latency.

Without knowing specifics there's no telling which would give more latency.  If someone is seeking the maximum performance from their mouse then that would be more on the selection of the mouse than on the decision to use the PS/2 adapter or not.

Answer (score 11):

These adapters are purely mechanical. There is no converter or whatever inside. So, **yes, the mouse/keyboard needs to do PS/2 by itself**.

Whether the controller IC inside the input device will perform worse with PS/2 will depend on how the protocol switch is made.

It is unlikely that PS/2 will perform noticably *different* than USB. From just looking at the connection specs, USB is vastly superior, both in speed and latency. Only USB host controller inefficiencies could lead to a worse overall experience.

[PS/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port) and USB share some properties that make an adapter feasible:

- 5 V
- Low current
- 2 “data” wires (though one is clock on PS/2).
- (two pins on PS/2 are unused)

Comment: You write "yes, the mouse/keyboard needs to do PS/2 by itself." <-- Well, yes but can you link to any usb keyboards that don't?  Every single usb keyboard I have tried has worked in ps2, so every single one i've tried has had that circuitry.

Comment: actually PS/2 ports have a lower latency than USB due to the fact that they send the signals directly to the processor via interrupts signals which is WAY WAY more efficient than the way USB connects to the processor. A lot of people say that there is no difference which is bs if you are into gaming because 10 ms difference is huge there. If you check your emails it does not matter sure. The reason I asked this question is because I want to connect my peripherals to the PS/2 and I was curios about the internal circuits that make it possible to communicate to both USB and PS/2

Comment: @Daniel,u write "It is unlikely that PS/2 will perform noticably different than USB. From just looking at the connection specs, USB is vastly superior, both in speed and latency" <--- Looking back to when we had computers with both USB and Ps2, it was clear Ps2 was vastly superior, much faster, much more responsive.I remember slower responsiveness hitting num lock on and off.. it was available on ps2 right from the start after num lock scroll lock and pause/break had flashed which was straight away. With USB it took a while to get itself together, and even then possibly not as responsive.

Comment: @yoyo_fun yes I agree with you yoyo, that relates to my experience too. And btw yoyo I think you may well  find that any USB keyboard you try will work in a ps2 socket.. If I recall it may even appear to be as responsive, but i'm not 100% sure.  If I recall correctly, the lights on the keyboard(even of a usb in a ps2), flash up  on when the computer boots up, (as with a pure ps2), and that's always a good sign.. I think you might find the num lock key would light up straight away if you pushed it. The adaptors are really cheap. They're very small.

Comment: @yoyo_fun btw there are ps2-usb adaptors i.e. going the other way, and they have a lot of circuitry in them and can be as big as half a fist.. But  usb-ps2 adaptors are small and I always found them to be more available in electronics stores, than the other way. Though nowadays you'd have to get them online.

Comment: @yoyo_fun Yes yes. It might appear more efficient. However, USB supports much higher polling rates and has a much higher protocol speed. It is unlikely you’ll notice any difference whatsoever today. Posthumous glorification won’t change that.

Comment: @DanielB Well it is not actually posthumous. Today, cheap motherboards may not all have ps/2 connectors the almost all expensive motherboards still have 2 separate ps/2 connectors. If USB would have been better at everything than PS/2 than it would have been widely used. However PS/2 still has some advantages and in some situations (gaming) it is better than USB. It also frees some processor clocks because in higher polling rates for USB the processor has to work harder. Also when more USB devices are connected that polling rate is splited among all devices unlike the PS/2 port.

Comment: Sorry, come back with the "USB and PS/2 are equivalent" argument when USB keyboard interfaces start supporting n-key rollover.

Comment: @CodyGray They do. I have one such keyboard right here.

Comment: As far as I know, the only way they can do that is by abusing the USB standard and presenting themselves as multiple keyboards. Working within the limits of the spec, all you get is a maximum of 6-key rollover, with the potential for some extra modifier keys thrown in there, prompting some keyboard manufacturers to report 8-key or 10-key rollover. Still a far cry from what PS/2 can do without any trickery, trickery which often causes trouble with switch boxes and other such devices.

Comment: Daniel, you said something that suggests that one would have to get a usb keyboard that supports ps2..(as if one has to be careful to). I've found that even the cheapest random ones on ebay do. I haven't run into one that doesn't.  Can you link to any usb keyboard .that does not?

Comment: @barlop I have at least three keyboards that didn't work with an adapter: MS Natural Keyboard 4000, Cooler Master Quickfire TK Stealth and some noname keyboard. And even if all keyboards were to support it, my statement would still be 100% true.

Comment: The USB HID standard supports NKRO. But it requires keyboards to boot with 6KRO for the sake of lazy BIOS programmers, and doesn't require them to implement NKRO. So lazy keyboard programmers take the path of least resistance. I think. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class#Keyboards http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/HID1_11.pdf

Comment: @DanielB you mentioned the Cooler Master Quickfire TK Stealth doesn't support PS2 but on their site, it's listed as a compatibility: https://www.coolermaster.com/us/en-us/catalog/peripheral/keyboards/quick-fire-stealth/#Specifications

Comment: That's another model generation. My model number is SGK-4021-GKCM1-DE. It did not come with an adapter and it doesn't work with one.

Comment: They also share a ground (GND) pin.

Comment: @barlop: Re *"Every single USB keyboard I have tried has worked in PS/2"*: Every single (expensive) [mechanical keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_technology#Mechanical-switch_keyboard) I have tested has ***not*** worked in PS/2 mode. Ironically, a lot of cheap USB keyboards (e.g., for sale in supermarkets) that I have tested work ***do*** as PS/2 ---

Comment: cont' - (I use the PS/2 ones as [macro keyboards](https://keyboardsexpert.com/macropad-mechanical-keyboard-faqs/), because they are much easier to interface to than the overcomplex USB (if the baud rate of the keyboard known, then there is even hardware support for it in microcontrollers ([UART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver/transmitter) hardware/[async serial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_serial_communication) ports)))

Comment: Unfortunately, PS/2 support in keyboards is [not documented anywhere](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2023/03/20/ps-2-support-on-modern-usb-keyboards#USB_support). Usually the only way to know is to purchase the keyboard (or get access to it in some other way). Speculation on my part: The PS/2 support in cheap USB keyboards is probably by accident: They probably use some old (cheap legacy) standard chipset/hardware that supports PS/2.

Comment: @PeterMortensen have you managed to find/use any bulkier adaptor? e.g. a Raspberry Pi could probably do it. (a Pi can act as a device).  Or, something like this https://www.blackbox.co.uk/gb-gb/fi/1307/12138/USB-to-PS-2-Flashable-Converter

Answer (score 5):

I can definitively answer the first part of the question,

*"IS there a necessity for the mouse to know a different protocol or a different pinout to be able to be connected to a PS/2 port ?"*

The answer is yes, a USB HID device (mice and keyboards) must understand the alternative PS/2 protocol in order to function in PS/2 port using USB-PS/2 adapter.

Not every USB mice or keyboard support the PS/2 mode. Presence of the green adapter in the OEM package warrants this compatibility, but the opposite is not true - some HID devices do support PS/2 mode even if the adapter is not included with the product, some don't, all depending on IC in use. For example, the Microsoft Notebook Optical Mouse P/N: X08-86056 does not work in PS/2 port.

Comment: No, PS/2 is detected (and switched to) at the hardware level: The [pull-up resistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-up_resistor) on the two USB data signals (D- and D+) in the PS/2 device (PS/2 signals DATA and CLK, respectively) are used on the PC side to detect a PS/2 device. The PC side then switches from USB hardware to PS/2 hardware.