# USB keyboard and USB-to-PS/2 adapter scancode

Tags: usb, keyboard, adapter, ps2, ps2-keyboard

I have configuration like this:
USB keyboard ---> USB-to-PS/2 adapter ---> PS/2 port.
Below is the image of the adapter.

[USB-to-PS/2 adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2wTt.jpg)

My question is which scancode will be produced at the end of the chain?
Will it be an USB scancode or PS/2 scancode (set 2 probably)?

After reading online, I'm not clear on this. Some say that the adapter has a chip which does USB to PS/2 translation, and others say that it is a straightforward pass-through connection.

Comment: So, it will be a USB scancode?

Comment: How would I know if the keyboard does that (apart from using an oscilloscope)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your "USB keyboard" does work in this combination (over PS/2 port), it means that this is a special "dual-mode" keyboard. It is designed to understand both USB 1.1 LS protocol and the alternative PS/2 protocol. Not all keyboards are made this way.

The adapter doesn't have any chip inside, it is just a passive connector. The keyboard switches automatically depending on what kind of initial signaling it sees from the port.

Not sure what do you mean by "scan code", but the port is PS/2, and operates as PS/2. It is the keyboard that enters the alternative PS/2 mode. and therefore work with PS/2 scancode **SET**. See also [this SE EE post](https://superuser.com/q/1150204/620011).

Comment: When I wrote "USB scancode" I meant HID Usage ID code. OK, so if the keyboard is dual-mode, then a PS/2 scancode from a set will be produced. If the keyboard doesn't support dual-mode and I plug it in a USB port, how will an ASCII be produced? It is clear for PS/2 keyboard (serial ---> scancode ---> ASCII), but what is the process for USB keyboard?

Comment: Nevermind, I found this on USB keyboard packets: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/20047/how-are-hids-keyboard-joypad-created-and-mapped. Thanks for your help Ale..chenski.

Comment: @evilpascal, this Microsoft document might help, http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/translate.pdf